# Set and use variables in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I created an Angular controller to list ebooks as follows:

```
function EBookListController() {

  var vm = this;

  vm.ebooks = [];
  vm.catalogSlug = null;
  vm.pagination = { pageNumber: 1, pageSize: 9 };

  vm.init = function (catalogSlug) {
    vm.catalogSlug = catalogSlug;
    load(vm.pageNumber, vm.pageSize);
  };

  vm.load = function (pageNumber, pageSize) {
    // Call service to load ebooks
  };

}
```

1. Should I define pagination default values in vm.pagination initialization or in init function?
2. Should load function have pageNumber and pageSize parameters or just use vm.pagination values?

Basically I am not sure if the functions should use the vm parameters values or always take them as arguments ...

Comment: It'll work either way. In general, I prefer passing all needed info in parameters. Easier to see all the dependencies.

Comment: Your load is defined of your `vm` object but used as a global. Anyhow methods defined of the scope i access the scope directly in them, makes it easier when binding them to directives int he view. Any global methods that may be defined in the controller but not added onto the scope i pass any scope properties into them. Makes it easier to extract that logic out into a service etc if ever needed.

Comment: @ste2425 In my opinion always having the parameters has one advantage: calling the function from within the controller or from within the view is the same ... Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `pageSize` a scope variable which can be accessed by page rendering functions.

It is enough to set the `catalogSlug` inside the `init()` function,

```
var vm = this;

vm.ebooks = [];
vm.pageSize = 9;

vm.init = function (catalogSlug) {
    vm.catalogSlug = catalogSlug;
    vm.load(1);
};

vm.load = function(pageNumber) {
   // Call service to load ebooks         

   // Render the pageNumber and use vm.pageSize to set it's size.
};
```

Comment: Sure they are accessible ... The question is if they should

Comment: I don't think your solution would work because I will have a button that when clicked should load the next page ... So I need to pass the pageValue to the load function ... How would you do it then?

Comment: Thanks. Updates the answer.